# Ansible How to get the windows update kb number

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get the pending installed windows update kb using ansible.

```yaml
       - name: Check for missing updates.
         win_updates:
           state: searched
           category_names: "{{ win_updates_categories }}"
         register: update_count
         ignore_errors: yes
    
    
       - debug: msg="{{ update_count.updates.kb }}"
```

but runs in error, could anyone help me, thank you !

Here is the output for register updatte

```
  - debug: 
      var: update_count

   "update_count": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "filtered_updates": {}, 
        "found_update_count": 1, 
        "installed_update_count": 0, 
        "reboot_required": false, 
        "updates": {
            "67eab6a6-099b-42c5-86ce-63681f58ebd2": {
                "categories": [
                    "Security Updates", 
                    "Windows Server 2016"
                ], 
                "id": "67eab6a6-099b-42c5-86ce-63681f58ebd2", 
                "installed": false, 
                "kb": [
                    "4593226"
                ], 
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error if i only want show kb info

```
  - debug: 
      var: update_count.updates.kb
    "update_count.updates.kb": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

Comment: Please add the error log

Comment: i have post the error logs in question

Answer (score 0):

Please see below, I used the {{ item.value.id }} to get the ID value (last task) and saving them in an array if they are more than one, same way you should be able to retrieve the KBs. hopefully this explains

## install critical updates only - reboot if nece

```
      - name: install category critical updates only
        win_updates: 
         category_names: ['CriticalUpdates']
         server_selection: windows_update
         state: installed
         
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: CriticalUpdateResults

      - name: Postgres Column Values assigned
        set_fact: UpdateCategory="{{ CriticalUpdateResults }}"

      - name: CriticalUpdates Category assigned
        set_fact: PatchCategory="CriticalUpdates"
      - name: UpdatesArray assigned space
        set_fact: 
         UpdatesArray: ""

      - name: UpdatesArray assigned None if no update count
        set_fact: 
         UpdatesArray: "None"
        when: UpdateCategory.found_update_count == 0


      - name: Updates Array assigned
        set_fact: 
         UpdatesArray: "{{ UpdatesArray }} {{ **item.value.id** }}"
        with_items:
         - "{{ UpdateCategory.updates | dict2items }}"
        when: UpdateCategory.found_update_count != 0
```